# ROuting entire Json Contents based on json field

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "From": "stuart",
    "Payload": {
        "Alert": "Critical",
        "Recipient": "Joe"
    }
}
```

I want to route this based on if the field in Alert is 'Critical' or not.

I've tried RouteOnAttribute processor and also an EvaluateJson processor. Neither are working.

For RouteOnAttribute I've tried

Alerted: `${Payload:jsonPath('$.Alert'):equals('Critical')}`

Then I have a relationship based on Alerted but nothing ever goes into my RouteOnAttribute processor, the queue just sits there till it fills to 10,000.

I need the full JSON to be routed, I can't lose information in the routing.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is with **jsonPath** function works on flowfile attributes but you are not having Payload attribute associated with the flowfile.

***How to add attribute to the flowfile?***

After generateflowfile processor use **EvaluateJsonPath** processor with **destination as flowfile-attribute**,

Add new property

**payload.alert as $.Payload.Alert**

[image]
Then use routeonattribute processor add new property as

**Alerted**

```
${payload.alert:equals('Critical')}
```

***Flow:***

```
1.GenerateFlowFile
2.EvaluateJsonPath //extract the value and keep as attribute to the flowfile
3.RouteOnAttribute //check the attribute value
```